# Creating publishers and subscribers based on a config file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a ROS bridge to an network of devices (think serial network).  The serial network connection must be managed by a single process (i.e. a single interface node).  I would like to create a flexible bridge node that would allow for any configuration of devices on the serial network.  As a result, I cannot hardcode topics the interface node will publish and subcribe to.  One solution is to load a yaml file on startup that would specify the topics, but I have not seen this done before.  Has anybody dynamically created multiple topics from a yaml file?  Are there any issues with this approach?  Is there a good example that I could look at?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11733/creating-publishers-and-subscribers-based-on-a-config-file/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2011-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should work without any problems. You can use the yaml file directly or alternately use it to load params and read out these params to create the topics.

For the creation topics are just strings that can come from anywhere.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1